# Pure Frontend CMS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, content-management-system

I'm currently redeveloping/designing a department website at my university, but an internal organization who handles the servers/current CMS system are being ridiculously uncooperative. I can't get access to the templates of the current CMS and I can't develop my own templates for the system, so I'm trying to move away from it (EZ Publish). But I also can't get admin access to a server, so I'm unable to install PHP/MySQL to get Wordpress up and running.

Basically, all I have access to right now is a `public/` folder. I'm considering writing a pure frontend app with backbone or something, but my boss wants the option of the dept heads to edit information. I want to avoid rolling together my own custom CMS if possible, so I was wondering if anyone knows of a pure front-end CMS manager that doesn't require a server language and server database.

Comment: What do you exactly have on the server-side? No admin access, no PHP, no MySQL - but how do you want to store data on the server?

Comment: I think I have access to perl. And as for data, there really isn't much. Just missions statements, office hours, and a bunch of images.

Comment: Then you could write a RESTful web service in PERL. It could store data in files (since you don't have a DB). The frontend could be written as a single-page web application. How much time do you have to write it? :)

Comment: A couple months. I think this is what I'll look into. Haven't used perl before though, should be interesting =p

Comment: Good luck with the project! Upload it to github when it's ready :)

Comment: For sure, I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

that's a hard one, first because you have to have a way to maintain the data and that's not possible in front end, if the server is working RESTfully, that may be possible, but in other cases, I don't think this is a choice, because no cms will be able to communicate with an existing server cms.

Comment: Well it can be done, but not in the most secure manner (not exactly a priority). My first thought would be to store every document as a text file, then read in and render using JavaScript. And I can develop an admin interface (again, not exactly super secure, though there are decent frontend security options out there) to allow the professors to edit the text files.

Comment: I just would really prefer to avoid that much development

Comment: this is really to much to handle, it's not only insecure, but very hard to maintain on the long run

Answer (score 0):

Host a wordpress somewhere else and install the [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api) plugin. Enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the remote server. Build Your frontend with static files that interact with the service. Host them in the buggers `public/` directory.

The admin/post editing tasks will have to be done on the backend host, but hopefuly you'll be able to get a subdomain from your university to point there.

Answer (score 0):

another approach to this problem is static website generators.

you can host the content and data for those in a university internal or other code repository and push the generated content to the site.

to allow your depearment heads to edit information, find a site generator that allows you to seperate structure and layout from content, so that they can edit simple text files to add content, hosted on a shared storage they can all access.